# How do I use 'select into' statement between two instances of SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, linked-server

Is there a way to do

```
SELECT A, B 
INTO [SERVER\INSTANCE_B].DATABASE.DBO.TABLE
FROM [SERVER\INSTANCE_A].DATABASE.DBO.TABLE
```

between instances? Do I have to create a linked server for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you have to create a linked server on one of the instances where you want to run this query to achieve this.

You can also use SQL Server Import and Export Wizard to transfer data if this is a one time transfer. You can right-click on the database where you want the data to be imported to and select `Tasks` --> `Import data...` or alternatively select the database where you want the data to be exported from and select `Tasks` --> `Export data...`

Comment: +1 for SQL Server Import & Export. Select into between linked servers doesn't perform well for big amount of data